# If A entails B, and B entails C, does A entail C?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic

Or does C entail A?
This is a most simple question that bothers me why I don't understand the answer. Propositional logic is very difficult for me. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Does $X$ entail $Y$ mean $X \implies Y$?

Comment: Yes! I do believe that is the correct symbol. Although in my textbook it looks like (If α ⊨ β  and β ⊨ γ then α ⊨ γ).

Comment: If so, then your question is whether $\bigg((A \implies B) \land (B \implies C)\bigg) \implies (A \implies C)$?  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Finally I understand! Thank you so very much!

Comment: See [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Propositional_logic).

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, OP confirms that $X$ entail $Y$ means $X \implies Y$.

Then the OP's question is whether
$$\bigg((A \implies B) \land (B \implies C)\bigg) \implies (A \implies C)$$
holds.

Hint: See [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Propositional_logic).